# Proven code won't upload to Arduino Uno R3

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino

So I just got me LED matrix in the mail and im trying to upload the code from this instructable http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Processing-Audio-Spectrum-Analyzer/?ALLSTEPS but I keep getting the errors

```
ArduinoCode:2: error: 'ht1632c' does not name a type
ArduinoCode.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
ArduinoCode:11: error: 'dotmatrix' was not declared in this scope
ArduinoCode.cpp: In function 'void loop()':
ArduinoCode:35: error: 'dotmatrix' was not declared in this scope
ArduinoCode:35: error: 'BLACK' was not declared in this scope
ArduinoCode:41: error: 'GREEN' was not declared in this scope
ArduinoCode:107: error: 'ORANGE' was not declared in this scope
ArduinoCode:131: error: 'RED' was not declared in this scope
ArduinoCode:153: error: 'dotmatrix' was not declared in this scope
```

The code is http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FSH/KZKA/GZ0BVJOC/FSHKZKAGZ0BVJOC.ino Because I still have no clue how to post code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error message because you don't have the  file (which is included from your program) in the libraries folder.

In the instructables that you mentioned they have an attachment called libary.zip file. Download and extract the zip file and copy the contents into the arduino libraries folder. Once you do it your code should compile properly.

Comment: So it turns out that was the problem, I somehow put the libraries in my codes folder.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, then make sure you mark it as the accepted answer. This will help others who are looking for unanswered questions to answer.